# Source code for functions Rand and Randn in Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, random

I'm student from Ariel University in Israel and I'm trying to implement Matlab RAND and RANDN in C# in such way that same input for Matlab and C# (with same seed) , Randn and Rand will give the same result in both languages.

for example:

In Matlab:

```
rand('seed',123)
disp(rand)
```

output: 0.0878

In C#:

```
Console.WriteLine(MyRand(123));
```

output:  0.0878

I think for implement this kind of functionality, I need to have the source code for RAND and RANDN in Matlab. Does anyone has this code and may share?

Thanks a lot,

Shimon

Comment: You're standing in a public space asking for someone to break the law by providing you with proprietary source code.  I, for one, will have nothing to do with such an enterprise.

Comment: Well, not unless I am handsomely rewarded.

Comment: rand by default uses the mersenne twister algorithm, which should be available in basically every programming language you can find.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get the source code :/ but you can see the algorithms they use in the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html but if they are parametric then I doubt you'll be able to exactly replicate their implementations. Ignoring your speed requirements, I would suggest using the Matlab .NET compiler and just use Matlab's (since I'm assuming you're doing this to compare a stochastic algorithm)

Comment: Note that `rand('seed',123)` is no longer recommended syntax for recent versions of matlab. If you try to reproduce their code I would recommend focussing on the lastest version.

Answer (score 3):

Doing:

```
>> s = RandStream.getGlobalStream()

s = 


mt19937ar random stream (current global stream)
             Seed: 0
  NormalTransform: Ziggurat
```

Your given the random-number-generator algorithm and the transformation used to get normal distributed numbers.
Both are publicly available algorithms.
Google gives you e.g.:

http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~%20m-mat/MT/MT2002/emt19937ar.html
and 
http://www.jstatsoft.org/v05/i08/paper

describing both algorithms including reference / example implemenations.

Comment: These are just the default methods of course – [many others are available](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-controlling-a-random-number-stream.html#brvku_2). Also note that the version of Mersenne Twister that Matlab uses is 10+ years out of date. In my experience, compiling the the newer versions to mex C achieved 2–3 times the performance. These newer codes have other features that are missing from Matlab's implementation as well.

Answer (score 2):

Randn is as far as i know MarsenneTwister. To verify this i would first try to use the MarsenneTwister from Apache and check for similar results: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/MersenneTwister.html

If so: Search for any implementation. This algorithm should be documented.

Answer (score 1):

But seriously, if you type

```
edit rand.m
```

into the Matlab command window, and

```
edit randn.m
```

I think you will get as much information as the Mathworks publish about those functions.  This information points towards the algorithms used and, for `rand` an implementation too.

Answer (score 1):

As your question only mentions obtaining the same results, I would recommend one of the following:

1. Generate a lot of random numbers, then use them one by one in both programming languages.
2. Implement your own (simple) random generator in both languages.